# How to extend logged-in user informations in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) as a base of my application. Now, I would like to extend current logged in user with additional information (user id and email address).
The goal is to beeing able to perform this operation in controller:
`authentication.getId()` or `authentication.getPrincipal().getId()`

In given tutorial i particularry don't understand few elements:

1. What's the role of UserDetailsServiceImpl?
2. What's going on with `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`?

In one place it is used like this:

```
private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

While in other in this way:

```
return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
```

Do I have to extend User class, or somehow UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?
Looking forward for your answers!

Comment: Just implement a custom `UserDetailsService` that does what you want. You don't need anything else. Also `authentication.getId()` or `authentication.getPrincipal().getId()` is something you will never be able to do, simply because those methods aren't defined on the interface.

Comment: So how to access logged-in user id in Controller?

Comment: You will need to cast to your user type.

Comment: Look at second code example in my post. There where is ```creds.getUsername(), creds.getPassword()``` what object type is created there? And in a first code example user is just a String. It seems strange/

Comment: No it isn't. The first is using a JWT token which is passed as a header, which is a String. Which is then parsed. The other one is just username/password authentication. However as stated it doesn't matter as you only need to implement your own `UserDetailsService` nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Could you tell me what exactly what needs to be done in ```UserDetailService```? Any particular function to Override? And what about ```authentication.getDetails()``` is this method then able to access information from userDetailService?

Comment: You are looking at things that don't matter. As stated implement the `UserDetailsService` (it is an interface from Spring Security) and let your custom user implement `UserDetails` and you will be able to find your user, return it and let Spring Security use it. That is all.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand or I'm doing something wrong. I added another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62303630/how-to-access-user-details-in-controller-using-spring-security  please look at this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a principal you want to `Authentication`:

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ...
        String username = getUsername(req);
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.findByUsername(username);
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(applicationUser, null, new ArrayList<>());

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

(On above example, set logged-in `ApplicationUser` as a principal.)

And then, controllers can obtain principal by `SecurityContext`:

```
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    ApplicationUser principal = (ApplicationUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
    System.out.println(principal.getId());
```

[Here is complete diff](https://github.com/yukihane/springboot-auth-updated/commit/bc14f84571d1b314f7a61394180069dd18ef7357).

---

> What's the role of UserDetailsServiceImpl?

[Here is `UserDetailsService` description](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#appendix-faq-what-is-userdetailservice):

> `UserDetailsService` is a DAO interface for loading data that is specific to a user account. It has no other function other to load that data for use by other components within the framework. It is not responsible for authenticating the user. Authenticating a user with a username/password combination is most commonly performed by the `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, which is injected with a `UserDetailsService` to allow it to load the password (and other data) for a user in order to compare it with the submitted value.

> What's going on with UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?

Commonly, used as [`DaoAuthenticationProvider#authenticate`'s argument](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.3.3.RELEASE/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java#L126)(see also [`supports`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.3.3.RELEASE/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java#L319-L322)).
On this tutorial, it is called by [`JWTAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/yukihane/springboot-auth-updated/blob/98fbdd7c1f/src/main/java/com/auth0/samples/authapi/springbootauthupdated/security/JWTAuthenticationFilter.java#L41).

On the other hand, [`JWTAuthorizationFilter`](https://github.com/yukihane/springboot-auth-updated/blob/98fbdd7c1f/src/main/java/com/auth0/samples/authapi/springbootauthupdated/security/JWTAuthorizationFilter.java#L54) also uses `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, but this type is not required here(merely used as `Authentication` implementation).