# How to access user details in Controller using Spring Security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I need to access currently logged-in user details (id or email address) in Controller. This is how I am trying to do so right now, and this doesn't work.

`ApplicationUser` is an `@Entity` in database.

UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository) {
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (applicationUser == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return builtCustomUser(applicationUser);
    }

    private User builtCustomUser(ApplicationUser applicationUser) {
        String username = applicationUser.getUsername();
        String password = applicationUser.getPassword();
        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        MyUser myUser = new MyUser(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, emptyList());

        return myUser;
    }
}
```

Custom User class:

```
public class MyUser extends User implements UserDetails {
    public MyUser(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
    }

    public MyUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
                  boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    }
}
```

That's how I am trying to access it in Controller:

```
MyUser mu = (MyUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

And this is error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class MyUser
```

Comment: Why the separate `MyUser` class? Just let your `ApplicationUser` implement `UserDetails` (the interface). WIthout knowing what you are doing in your controller (that single line isn't enough) it is impossible to find out what is wrong with that code.

Comment: I don't do anything in Controller. This single line is causing the problem, I just want System.out.println user id nothing more.

Comment: You are getting the authentication from somewhere.

Comment: Like I said (and showed) in previous post, Authroization filter returns UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken with STRING (getSubject() from token). Mayby there is a problem? I Checked, and it is possible to put there ApplicationUser class, and then it is accessible in Controller. Is it a bad solution?

Comment: [Your code](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/en62303630) runs as expected, on my environment.

Comment: ANd as I stated also in your other post you don't need that... You only need a `UserDetailsService` the rest is handled by Spring Security. However you are replacing too many parts and have no clue on what those do.

Comment: @出羽和之 Thats super strange, but thank you for confirmation, maybe could you also look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263667/how-to-extend-logged-in-user-informations-in-spring-security (this is my initial problem). Praticulary on a part, where UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is returned with user as a String from Token .getSubject()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62263667/4506703), actual type of `Authentication` is [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`](https://github.com/yukihane/springboot-auth-updated/blob/98fbdd7c1f76b07710e11a24dd3ebafc47fee2b2/src/main/java/com/auth0/samples/authapi/springbootauthupdated/security/JWTAuthorizationFilter.java#L38-L40), and return type of `getPrincipal()` is `String`, [username](https://github.com/yukihane/springboot-auth-updated/blob/98fbdd7c1f76b07710e11a24dd3ebafc47fee2b2/src/main/java/com/auth0/samples/authapi/springbootauthupdated/security/JWTAuthorizationFilter.java#L54).

You can set any other `Authentication` implementation instead of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` to [`SecurityContext`](https://github.com/yukihane/springboot-auth-updated/blob/98fbdd7c1f76b07710e11a24dd3ebafc47fee2b2/src/main/java/com/auth0/samples/authapi/springbootauthupdated/security/JWTAuthorizationFilter.java#L40), and principal type is free(so you can set `MyUser`), too.